# Unable to add app to teams using Microsoft graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created a MS Team's app package. I have uploaded it to my organization using teams service admin credentials.(ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/tenant-apps-catalog-teams?toc=/microsoftteams/platform/toc.json&bc=/MicrosoftTeams/breadcrumb/toc.json).
 I am trying to add this app to a team by using 'Add app to team' API(ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). 
I am getting '404 not found' error. 
I am using the id provided in the team's app package in the request body.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id must be "the catalog app's generated app ID (different from the developer-provided ID in the Microsoft Teams zip app package." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamsapp?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Once the app is deployed to the app catalog, you then must query the app catalog, filtering on the external id. (e.g.  externalId eq '{teamsAppManifestId}')

Comment: Thanks you for your response. I am following this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging#deploy-your-app-to-your-tenant-app-catalog). They have mentioned that id provided in the zip app package can be used to install the app for users.